# Do we need /efi or just /uefi?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there any point in having separate tags [efi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efi) and [uefi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uefi)? EFI and UEFI are [different versions of the same standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#History). Most if not all questions are about 2.x (“UEFI”) versions, not about the 1.x “EFI” versions, so we should either clean up [efi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efi) to be only about the actual EFI versions or merge it into [uefi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uefi).

Comment: I don't know enough about this to know when to tag with one or the other so I can't really help. I'd be happy to merge the two if that's what's decided.

Comment: IIRC IBM system x uses EFI. It may be worth keeping them separate just so people asking questions about older high end servers aren't approached by people whose knowledge is with more recent versions. A lot of times you need to know how the older iteration worked. Knowing how the newer versions work and inferring from that isn't always helpful, especially when the hardware itself may pose unique challenges.

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is that if you've tagged a question as being [tag:efi] and not [tag:uefi] it's reasonable to assume that part of your question may involve experience the hardware that used to run EFI. UEFI is pretty across the board, in contrast.

Comment: @Bratchley Do we have questions that are about EFI and not about UEFI? Because if we don't then a separate [tag:efi] tag is doing more harm than good.

Comment: tbh now that I look at how thoroughly misused the [tag:efi] tag is, it pretty much is a [tag:uefi] synonym except without being an actual one (which may have been your point up above). I still think that for the next few years there's a strong argument for keeping them separate (UEFI is still relatively new to broader public) but if people are going to misuse it en masse like that, it's probably a moot point.

Answer (score 5):

Merging makes sense for the most part, the only significant user visible difference that has made itself felt is secure boot, which is only available in uefi. If you turn off secure boot the typical user will not be able to tell the difference. The real differences between versions would be visible to developers so I would recommend against merging them on stackoverflow (unless there was significant confusion) and for merging here unless there is general disgust with secure boot amongst the efi folks, even so anyone who knows efi will know how to deal with that.